# Foreign Key CRUD Display Name

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I currently have the following model in an ASP.NET MVC5 project:

ComponentModel.cs

```
public class Component
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Equipment Name")]
    public int EquipmentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Motor Name")]
    public int MotorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Gearbox Name")]
    public int GearboxId { get; set; }

    public virtual Equipment Equipment { get; set; }
    public virtual Motor Motor { get; set; }
    public virtual Gearbox Gearbox { get; set; }
}
```

MotorModel.cs (same format for Motor, Gearbox and Equipment Models)

```
public class Motor 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }
}
```

However, when generating a controller using scaffolding is correctly shows the selectable values from the database tables but the names are displaying as EquipmentId, MotorId and GearboxId, nor are the fields validating as required.

What am I missing to get the display names correct and the fields validating as expected?

**Update 1 - Create View**

```
....    

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Component</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUri, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageUri, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageUri, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EquipmentId, "EquipmentId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EquipmentId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EquipmentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MotorId, "MotorId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("MotorId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MotorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GearboxId, "GearboxId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("GearboxId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GearboxId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the generated view file?

Comment: @StephenReindl - updated to show the view. Thanks :)

Comment: Changing the label in the view works (as expected), however that still doesn't fix the validation. Clicking submit on the form validates all fields apart from the equipment, gearbox and motor dropdowns

Comment: If you enter the action and trace your code with the debugger, are the values for EquipmentId, MotorId and GearboxId filled?